# Convergence of $ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac { n ! n ^ { n } } { ( 2 n ) ! } $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The task is to find out if this series is convergent or divergent.

> $$ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac { n ! n ^ { n } } { ( 2 n ) ! } $$

The solution uses the ratio test and says:

> $ \left.\begin{aligned} \frac { a _ { n + 1 } } { a _ { n } } & = \frac { ( n + 1 ) ! ( n + 1 ) ^ { n + 1 } ( 2 n ) ! } { ( 2 ( n + 1 ) ) ! n ! n ^ { n } } = \frac { ( n + 1 ) n ! ( n + 1 ) ( n + 1 ) ^ { n } ( 2 n ) ! } { ( 2 n + 2 ) ( 2 n + 1 ) ( 2 n ) ! n ! n ^ { n } } \\ & = \frac { ( n + 1 ) ( n + 1 ) } { ( 2 n + 2 ) ( 2 n + 1 ) } \cdot \left( \frac { n + 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n } = \frac { \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) } { \left( 2 + \frac { 2 } { n } \right) \left( 2 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) } \cdot \left( \frac { n + 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n } \\ & \rightarrow \frac { 1 } { 4 } \cdot e < 1 \text { for } n \rightarrow \infty \end{aligned} \right. $

I understand every step until here

> $$ \frac { \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) } { \left( 2 + \frac { 2 } { n } \right) \left( 2 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) } \cdot \left( \frac { n + 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n } $$

How can all n's on the left site become 1/n? And I understand how the left site can become $\frac{1}{4}$, but how can the right site become e in the last step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$$

Divide both denominator and numerator by $n^2 $

$$\frac{\frac{(n+1)}{n}\frac{(n+1)}{n}}{\frac{(2n+2)}{n}\frac{(2n+1)}{n}}\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$$
$$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{1}{n})}{(2+\frac{2}{n})(2+\frac{1}{n})}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{1}{n})}{(2+\frac{2}{n})(2+\frac{1}{n})}=\frac{1\cdot 1}{2 \cdot 2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
and$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Multiply by $$ \frac{1/n^2}{1/n^2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

We have that

$$\left( \frac { n + 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n }=\left( 1+\frac { 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n }\to e$$

and from here

$$\frac { ( n + 1 ) ( n + 1 ) } { ( 2 n + 2 ) ( 2 n + 1 ) } $$

just divide both numerator and denominator by $n^2$.

Comment: A combination of our answers provides a complete answer!

Comment: @Sobi yes we can make a 50/50 for the 15 rep points :P

Comment: (+0.5) I've given you each half an upvote

Comment: @Jam LoL :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> How can all n's on the left site become 1/n?

This is a standard method when finding the limit of such sequences.
You factor out the highest power of $n$ to cancel it out.

So if we would like to involve one more step befor the one you do not follow it would be:

$\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\frac{n^2(1+1/n)(1+1/n)}{n^2(2+2/n)(2+1/n)}\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$

Also note, that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, is that just a fixed rule to memorize that $ \lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n } = e $ or how can I know that?

Comment: @Viviana No, it is not a fixed rule. It is often used as definition of $e$. You should have proofed that in your lecture. You might go and check it. You can not just say it is a fixed rule, because you would need to know, that the sequence above converges for example. But as I said. More details should be found in your lecture notes. It is a common limit every student has to know!

Answer (score 3):

In order to find an explicit value for the given series, we may recall that for any $|x|<\frac{1}{e}$ we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!} x^n = -W(-x) $$
with $W(x)$ being the inverse function of $x e^x$ ([Lambert's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)), by Lagrange inversion theorem.
A rapid sequence of formal manipulations:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!} x^{n}=\frac{-W(-x)}{1+W(-x)} $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!} x^{2n+1}=\frac{-x W(-x^2)}{1+W(-x^2)} $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!}(2n+1) x^{2n}=\frac{-x W(-x^2)}{1+W(-x^2)} $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!}(2n+1) x^{n}=\frac{-3W(-x)-2W(-x)^2-W(-x)^3}{(1+W(-x))^3} $$
and by replacing $x$ with $x(1-x)$, then applying $\int_{0}^{1}(\ldots)\,dx$, we get
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n n!}{(2n)!} &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-3W(-x(1-x))-2W(-x(1-x))^2-W(-x(1-x))^3}{(1+W(-x(1-x)))^3}\,dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-3W\left(\frac{t^2-1}{4}\right)-2W\left(\frac{t^2-1}{4}\right)^2-W\left(\frac{t^2-1}{4}\right)^3}{\left(1+W\left(\frac{t^2-1}{4}\right)\right)^3}\,dt\\&=&2\int_{-1/4}^{0}\frac{-3W(t)-2W(t)^2-W(t)^3}{\sqrt{1+4t}(1+W(t))^3}\,dt\\&=&\int_{W(-1/4)}^{0}-\frac{2 e^x x (3+2x+x^2)}{(1+x)^2 \sqrt{1+4 e^x x}}\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the last function is clearly integrable on $\left(W(-1/4),0\right)$. This integral representation is also a good way for deriving that the value of the wanted series is $\approx 1.53261$. An alternative derivation of an upper bound comes from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the identities
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}e^n = \frac{e}{4-e}+\frac{4\sqrt{e}}{(4-e)^{3/2}}\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}\right),$$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!e^n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+W\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Divide both the numerator and denominator on the left side by $n^2$.

As n approaches $\infty$, the 1/n and 2/n tend to zero, giving $\frac{(1)(1)}{(2)(2)}$ = $\frac{1}{4}$.

The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n+1}{n})^n$ = $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ = *e*.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac { n ! n ^ { n } } { ( 2 n ) ! }
$

For region of convergence,
just replace $n!$ with
$(n/e)^n$
and then use the
n-th root test.
The additional
$\sqrt{n}$
only affects the boundaries.

In this case
(why the annoying spaces?),
$\dfrac{n!n^{n}}{(2n)!}
$
becomes
$\dfrac{(n/e)^nn^{n}}{(2n/e)^{2n}}
=\left(\dfrac{(n/e)n}{(2n/e)^{2}}\right)^n
=\left(\dfrac{n^2e^2}{4n^2e}\right)^n
=\left(\dfrac{e}{4}\right)^n
$

Since
$\dfrac{e}{4} < 1$,
the sum converges.